# Problem in connecting node.js api on heroku with mongoDb atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I am attaching my github repo link for reference to the code. https://github.com/speedynik/NodewithMosh

Basically my heroku logs give different errors related to mongoDB connection.

what I have already verified => 
IP whitelist .. done

user on mongo ..  created

Infact my mongoDb compass does connect to by mongodb in atlas.

### Can someone please have alook at the code and point out the problem? its related to mongoDb connection string as far as I know.

c:\heroku config (for reference)
=== we2-india Config Vars
MONGODB_URI: mongodb+srv://:@we2india-00raw.mongodb.net/admin?retryWrites=true

NODE_ENV:                   production

nodewithmosh_jwtPrivateKey: kaju

---

Thank you

Comment: that link did not help as I have already done what is suggested there. I  want clarity as to where to use the mongoDB connection string in the API? Currently I am providing that as a "env" variable. I am using that variable in my custom-environment-variables.json file in my app. Everywhere else I provide the localhost connection string in the app.

Comment: Somebody please have a look guys. thank you